# Converting list to nested dictionary

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, dictionary

How can I convert a `list` into nested `dictionary'?

For example:

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I'd like to convert it to a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
```

Answer (score 7):

For that reverse the list, then start creating the empty dictionary element.

```
l = [1, 2, 3, 4]
d = {}
for i in reversed(l):
    d = {i: d}

>>> print(d)
{1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
```

Comment: for i in rl:
 d={i:d}    here rl=l[-1:] where l is a list and d is dictionary

Comment: d={}  for i in rl: d={i:d}

Comment: i forgot how to reverse .. just check the screen shot

Answer (score 4):

You could also use [`functools.reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) for this.

```
reduce(lambda cur, k: {k: cur}, reversed(l), {})
```

**Demo**

```
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> l = [1, 2, 3, 4]

>>> reduce(lambda cur, k: {k: cur}, reversed(l), {})
{1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
```

---

The flow of construction looks something like

```
{4: {}} -> {3: {4: {}} -> {2: {3: {4: {}}}} -> {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}
```

as `reduce` traverses the reverse iterator making a new single-element dict.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
l = [1,2,3,4]
d = {}

for i in l[::-1]:
    d = {i: d}

print(d)
```

> {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}} [Finished in 0.4s]

Answer (score 1):

Here is an abstraction.  Uses for `setdefault` are typically overshadowed by `defaultdict`, but here is an interesting application if you have one or more lists (iterables):

```
def make_nested_dict(*iterables):
    """Return a nested dictionary."""
    d = {}
    for it in iterables:
        temp = d
        for i in it:
            temp = temp.setdefault(i, {})
    return d

make_nested_dict([1, 2, 3, 4])
# {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}}

make_nested_dict([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6])
# {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}}}, 5: {6: {}}}
```

---

**Nested Branches**

Unlike `defaultdict`, this technique accepts duplicate keys by appending to existing "branches".  For example, we will append a new `7 → 8` branch at the third level of the first (A) branch:

```
                       A         B           C            
make_nested_dict([1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6], [1, 2, 7, 8])
# {1: {2: {3: {4: {}}, 7: {8: {}}}}, 5: {6: {}}}
```

Visually:

```
1 → 2 → 3 → 4   (A)            5 → 6   (B)
       \ 
        7 → 8   (C)
```